# converting number to string with specified order in sql

Tags: sql

I need the records order by month on school year, ex

```
August
September
October 
November
December
January
February 
March
April
May 
June
```

To get that order i found this order by but is returning the records with numbers and i need the name of the month. How can i get the name of the month without affecting the order?

```
SELECT  CASE
        When G.MO = 8 then 'August'
        When G.MO = 9 then 'September'
        When G.MO = 10 then 'October'
        When G.MO = 11 then 'November'
        When G.MO = 12 then 'December'
        When G.MO = 1 then 'January'
        When G.MO = 2 then 'February'
        When G.MO = 3 then 'March'
        When G.MO = 4 then 'April'
        When G.MO = 5 then 'May'
        When G.MO = 6 then 'June'
        When G.MO = 7 then 'July'
        end as [Month]
,...
from TABLE
group by [Month]
order by convert(nvarchar,(CASE WHEN CAST(LEFT(G.MO, 2) AS int) >= 8 THEN CAST(LEFT(G.MO, 2) AS int) - 8 ELSE CAST(LEFT(G.MO, 2) AS int) + 4 END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Usual way to rotate a sequence is [mod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) function.

```
ordre by (g.mod+4)%12
--(8+4)%12=0
--(9+4)%12=1
--...
--(7+4)%12=11
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple comparison to put the months after august first:

```
order by (case when g.mo >= 8 then 1 else 2 end),
         g.mo
```

Also, you can simplify the naming by doing:

```
select datename(month, cast(replace('2000-@mon-01', '@mon', g.mo) as date))
```

The `cast()` is actually not necessary, but I much prefer explicit conversion to implicit conversion.